# When overriding sync methods what are my options if I want to do an async operation

Tags: c#, async-await

Let's assume that I want to implement the following class that I don't own the code for; e.g., in BCL or a NuGet package:

```cs
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public abstract void Move();

    public abstract int GetSpeed();
}
```

And in the implementation, I will make an async operation:

```cs
public class Car
{
    public void Move()
    {
        StartEngineAsync(); // This is an async method call
        // do other stuff
    }

    public int GetSpeed()
    {
        var speed = CalculateSpeedAsync(); // This is an async method call
        // do other stuff
        return speed;
    }
}
```

Obviously, the code above does not work, using `await` (especially on the second method) also do not work, and using `CalculateSpeedAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` or `CalculateSpeedAsync().Result` is not recommended. So, what are my options?

Comment: there are 2 options 1. rewrite Vehicle in "async way"(which is pretty easy like `void` => `Task` `int` =>`Task<int>`) 2. use not recommend stuff(which makes this question a duplicate of "Calling async method synchronously")

Comment: The recommendation is not to do "async-over-sync" or "sync-over-async". Asynchronous flow is fundamentally different from sync and should be treated as such.

Comment: Are you sure that making that code async would even be of any benefit? I highly doubt it.

Comment: You already know about the solutions that aren't recommended and (hopefully) why they're not recommended, so what options would you like other than those? The reason it's not recommended is not because there are smarter ways, but because bolting together sync and async has fundamental problems. It can easily lead to mysterious deadlocks that are not at all pleasant to debug, even if you're not doing anything with a UI framework. You have to really know your stuff to do it safely, to the point where any benefit you think you'd get probably evaporates in the added complexity.

Comment: I modified the question to clarify that I don't own the code for `Vehicle`, that's why I'm in this dilemma :)

Comment: While not ideal, calling .GetAwaiter().GetResult() isn't the end of the world and I've seen it used in production code if you're not doing something critical or high performance. Take this with a grain of salt, though. Pure curiosity: what's the situation you find yourself in, extending code that you don't own? Is this code that someone else in your organization owns? There are some fights that aren't worth having but petitioning for best async practices is actually pretty worthwhile.

Comment: @Slothario, not necessarily, but can be. I'm mainly talking about a scenario where you're inheriting a class that is in library that you don't own; think BCL or a NuGet package. As an example, if I want a create my customised version of `JsonConfigurationProvider` I'll override `void Load(Stream stream)` and it's not an async method, doing any async operation inside it will put me in the situation that I'm asking about.

Comment: Can you use composition instead of inheritance? E.g. use the JsonConfigurationProvider in your own class which does asynchronous operations?

Comment: Keeping all the `async` completely `async` (no callbacks into sync code!) calling it through `Task.Run()` and using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on that is probably the safest approach (as in, least deadlock-prone) but you will still not get much benefit in the way of performance or scalability, which is the main thing that makes `async`/`await` attractive in the first place. It's typically not much more work to just write all your code sync for this particular scenario.

Comment: Why is wrapping the call in `Task.Run()` and calling `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is a better option than just calling `CalculateSpeedAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

Comment: @Slothario, I'll lose the "pluggability"

Comment: @CodeAddict: because using `Task.Run`/`TaskFactory.CreateNew` guarantees (or at least can be used to guarantee, with proper arguments) that a separate synchronization context is drafted into existence and that you're using the default thread pool scheduler, which minimizes the chance of something going wrong if your sync-over-async code happens to be called again from somewhere deeper in the call stack, possibly from different `async` code and a different context, which can lead to the aforementioned mysterious deadlocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The recommended way**

The only way that won't have side effects is to rewrite `StartEngineAsync()` to be synchronous. You can keep the asynchronous version, if other parts of your code use it properly, but you can create a new `StartEngine()` method that is purely synchronous.

Microsoft does this. They do sometimes provide synchronous and asynchronous methods to do the same thing, but their implementations are *completely* different. They don't just wrap the asynchronous method.

You can see this in their source code. For example, compare [`File.InternalReadAllText()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L290) (which is used by [`File.ReadAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.0)) with [`File.InternalReadAllTextAsync()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L699) (which is used by [`File.ReadAllTextAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltextasync?view=netcore-3.0)).

**Not recommended ways**

Every other way will be some version of waiting synchronously on asynchronous code. There are several ways, all with their caveats:

- Use `async void`. This will work for `Move()` but not `GetSpeed()` (since it needs a return value). Using `async void` will let you use `await`, but at the first `await` that acts on an incomplete `Task`, your method returns. Since it's `void`, it can't return a `Task`, which means that whoever called the method cannot wait until it completes. This means that everything after the first `await` will complete "in the background", somewhere. The calling method will also have no idea if it fails. That's Bad™
- Use `.Result`. Can cause deadlocks. That's Bad™. And exceptions are not unwrapped, which is annoying.
- Use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Can cause deadlocks. That's Bad™. But it unwraps any exceptions at least, as you'd normally expect.

The method in Fahad's answer starts your method on a different thread in a different context, which you just have to be aware of.

Some good reading: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below.

```
public static class AsyncHelper
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory _taskFactory = new
        TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
                    TaskCreationOptions.None,
                    TaskContinuationOptions.None,
                    TaskScheduler.Default);

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes an async Task method which has a void return value synchronously
    /// USAGE: AsyncUtil.RunSync(() => AsyncMethod());
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task">Task method to execute</param>
    public static void RunSync(Func<Task> task)
        => _taskFactory
            .StartNew(task)
            .Unwrap()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes an async Task<T> method which has a T return type synchronously
    /// USAGE: T result = AsyncUtil.RunSync(() => AsyncMethod<T>());
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">Return Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="task">Task<T> method to execute</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> task)
        => _taskFactory
            .StartNew(task)
            .Unwrap()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
}
```

Usage:

```
AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => CalculateSpeedAsync());
```

Comment: Can you explain how is that better than just calling `CalculateSpeedAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

Comment: It’s basically the only decent way to perform an async-within-sync call. The helper class basically creates, configure and starts an async task on-the-fly, then unwraps it and synchronously wait for its result: just like the await method, this approach will prevent deadlocks and could be used within a try/catch block to get the exception raised by the AsyncMethod itself.

References:
https://www.ryadel.com/en/asyncutil-c-helper-class-async-method-sync-result-wait/
https://cpratt.co/async-tips-tricks/

Comment: Be aware that this will start the task on a new thread, which may or may not be desirable, or may just not work right with UI apps.

Comment: Well you are correct about UI apps. However in a web application scenario, keeping the context If you don't need to restore that context later, it's just wasted resources. Even when you use async/await you should always use it like:
    `await DoSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`
You should pretty much always do this, unless there's a specific reason to keep the context.